# Rails: Почему не работает ссылка url_for(contoller: name, action: name, subdomain: name)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть ссылка формата:

```
= link_to 'форум', url_for(controller: 'forum', action: 'index', subdomain: 'forum')
```

В итоге получаю только `/forum`, без всяких поддоменов.

Пробовал **subdomain_fu** - та же ерунда.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= link_to 'форум', url_for(controller: 'forum', action: 'index', subdomain: 'forum', only_path: false)
```